# Invoke instance method which is held in a string variable

Tags: c#, methods, instance

I am trying to specify folders in Outlook using Interop.Outlook.

So in order to do that I use following methods:

```
Outlook.Folder targetFolder = ParentFolder.Folders["Level-1 Folder"] as Outlook.Folder;
```

This works generally ok but sometimes I will have to go more lower then a subfolder. I may need to go into sub-subfolder, like that:

```
Outlook.Folder targetFolder = ParentFolder.Folders["Level-1 Folder"].Folders["Level-2 Folder"] as Outlook.Folder;
```

I wonder if it is possible to use the Folder method from a variable. Please take a look on how I would imagine that:

```
string myMethod = "Folders["Level-1 Folder"].Folders["Level-2 Folder"]";
Outlook.Folder targetFolder = ParentFolder. + myMethod;
```

Thanks for your anwsers.

Regards,
W

Comment: Why? This looks like an xy problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I wonder if it is possible to use the Folder method from a variable.* Well, thats what you did in `ParentFolder.Folders["Level-1 Folder"]`. `ParentFolder` is a variable.

Just write

```
Outlook.Folder subfolder = targetFolder.Folders["Level-2 Folder"] as Outlook.Folder;
```

I am not sure why you think a method name has to be passed as string. Btw. `Folders` is an indexer.

It makes no difference whether you chain the indexes or not

```
var x = a.f["a"].f["b"].f["c"];
```

is the same as

```
var x = a.f["a"];
x = x.f["b"];
x = x.f["c"];
```

What changes from level to level is the folder name (index), which could be in a variable. You could write

```
string index;
var targetFolder = ParentFolder as Outlook.Folder;

index = "Level-1 Folder";
targetFolder = targetFolder.Folders[index] as Outlook.Folder;
index = "Level-2 Folder";
targetFolder = targetFolder.Folders[index] as Outlook.Folder;
index = "Level-3 Folder";
targetFolder = targetFolder.Folders[index] as Outlook.Folder;
```

So you have exact the same statement at each level, except that the folder name changes. Or:

```
var indexes = new string[] { "Level-1 Folder", "Level-2 Folder", "Level-3 Folder" };
var targetFolder = ParentFolder as Outlook.Folder;

foreach (string index in indexes) {
    targetFolder = targetFolder.Folders[index] as Outlook.Folder;
}
```

Comment: That is very helpful! Thank you very much!